# Google Analytics 4 setup email report

Tags: google-analytics

I have checked [Analytics Help](https://support.google.com/analytics#topic=9143232) and the best I can find on it is just a [Share / export reports](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9317657?hl=en&ref_topic=9303476) link.

Is the email report gone from Google Analytics 4 and I just have to use share link ?

Answer (score 1):

google support chat:
"We dont have that option at all in Google Analytics 4."

So options are share link or export